# Linux - when launching .desktop file Java application stays in "Starting MyApp"

Tags: java, linux, redhat

I created a my-app.desktop file for Linux, in this case it is Red Hat 6u9. When I double-click it, the application stays in **"Starting MyApp"**, then after a while disappears. But when trying the command java -jar /path_to_myapp/myapp.jar it works. How can I get more detailed information about what the problem is? I have also searched how to debug the launching of a .desktop file but without success, also I have tried to enable remote debugging, but again without success. My desktop file looks like this:

```
Exec=java -jar /home/rscvespa/rscvespa.jar GenericName=RSCVespa Icon=/home/rscvespa/rscvespa.ico Name=RSCVespa StartupNotify=true Terminal=false Type=Application Path=/home/rscvespa/ X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also try to point directly the jar Exec=java/home/rscvespa/rscvespa.jar . I cannot test it here but should be something simple

Comment: Hello Carlos, I already checked the permissions for the file and I have put the Terminal to true. Also I have tried what you have suggested:  Exec=java /home/rscvespa/rscvespa.jar, but with the same result unfortunately. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: sorry there was a typo, I wanted to write this "Exec=/home/rscvespa/rscvespa.jar" and try with Terminal with both values

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested, but without any luck :(

Comment: make sure your jar is executable (chmod +x /home/rscvespa/rscvespa.jar)

Comment: It already has all the rights .... I do not know what else to do and I have tried a lot of stuff before.

Comment: In fact I need somehow to see the output when i launch the .desktop file ...

Comment: maybe these links can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/where-is-log-file-of-gnome-3 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal

Comment: Hi Carlos, I found out, after reading ~/.xsession-errors, that a library needed by the application is not found. CLASSPATH is set in ~/.bashrc. So, if I launch the java app from a terminal, it is working correctly, but if I try to launch it directly from desktop, it is not working. For whatever reason, the .bashrc is not executed if launch directly from Desktop. Where should I declare the CLASSPATH variable to be recognized/read by application?